# TFS 2017 build executing powershell failing due to term not recognized error on line 1

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-pipelines

I'm pretty new to TFS and I'm still learning how to use it (so hopefully this isn't just a stupid oversight on my end). I'm working an internship this summer at a seasonal developer position, and essentially my end goal is to automate load testing for the company's website. I'm using TFS to achieve this goal; the build I currently have has two tasks only right now: one to start the controller and the testing environment, and one to stop them. My problem is that the build keeps failing before it really even starts, due to a "term not recognized" error on line 1, specifically caused by what appears to be the default working folder not being recognized.

Here are the relevant log files:

```
2019-05-30T20:00:02.0942883Z Executing the following powershell script. (workingFolder = D:\RM_agent\_work\11\s)
2019-05-30T20:00:02.0942883Z D:\RM_agent\_work\11\s 
2019-05-30T20:00:02.4999117Z ##[error]. : The term 'D:\RM_agent\_work\11\s' is not recognized as the name of a 
2019-05-30T20:00:02.4999117Z ##[error]cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
2019-05-30T20:00:02.4999117Z ##[error]name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
2019-05-30T20:00:02.4999117Z ##[error]At line:1 char:3
2019-05-30T20:00:02.4999117Z ##[error]+ . 'D:\RM_agent\_work\11\s'
2019-05-30T20:00:02.4999117Z ##[error]+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2019-05-30T20:00:02.4999117Z ##[error]    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\RM_agent\_work\11\s:String)  
2019-05-30T20:00:02.4999117Z ##[error]   [], CommandNotFoundException
2019-05-30T20:00:02.4999117Z ##[error]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I know that the working folder defaults to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`, so I'm assuming that `D:\RM_agent\_work\11\s` is what `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` evaluates to. `RM_agent` is obviously an agent, so `/_work/11/s` should be the local path where it stores the source code. Why is it unrecognized then?

I tried manually setting the working folder for the scripts through tfs to the folder where the build is stored, but the build still failed and the logs still showed that `workingFolder = D:\RM_agent\_work\11\s`.

[image]

Additionally, the line of code that the build is failing on, `Executing the following powershell script. (workingFolder = D:\RM_agent\_work\11\s)`, is nowhere in the script I am trying to execute, which confuses me. Where is this script coming from?

(I can remove this if it doesn't fit the guidelines/is off topic, but if anyone could point me towards any resources about tfs and/or load testing it would be massively helpful as well)

EDIT: Here is the powershell script for the first task

```
########################################
# start environment
########################################

# import modules
Import-Module '\\neenah-san1\TSbuild\Deployment\Tools\PowerShell\Azure\JJK.TS.Azure.psm1' -Force -Prefix 'TS'

# provide azure credentials
$credential = Get-Credential

# login to azure subscription
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential

# start the controller
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName 'TS-LoadTest-TST' | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'vstc'} | Start-TSAzureVM -Credential $credential

# wait for controller to fully start
Start-Sleep -Seconds 120

# start the agents
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName 'TS-LoadTest-TST' | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'vsta'} | Start-TSAzureVM -Credential $credential

# check status of all servers
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName 'TS-LoadTest-TST' -Status | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -Property Name, PowerState | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Solution structure:
[image]

EDIT 2: [RESOLVED] It's all fixed now, thank you! I went into the repository and mapped the folder my scripts were in directly to `$(build.sourcesDirectory)`. Consequently I was able to change the file path to `$(build.sourcesDirectory)\StartControllerAndAgents.ps1` and the build is now able to find the files to run.

Comment: What does your script look like?

Comment: @jessehouwing Here's the tfs config [imgur] (https://imgur.com/a/X21Frhf) and this is what the solution path looks like [imgur] (https://imgur.com/cFEhB9M)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the path to the script as `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Path\To\Script`. Not the TFVC path which you've configured now `$/Project/Path/To/Script`.

The exact path depends on the workspace mapping of the build definition.

The same applies to the working directory.

There are a number of variables in Azure Pipelines (the current name for the Build hub in TFS/Azure DevOps) that resolve to different standardized paths on the agent. Almost all tasks take a relative path off of those variables.